# How @Bean is used in a class without @Configuration when configuring Spring Security in a Spring Boot app?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, javabeans

I'm learning about Spring Security in a Spring Boot app. I know that you need to use @Bean only in a @Configuration class. But I see this example for configuration Spring Security and the @Bean is used in a class without @Configuration. How is this possible? Thank you!

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you forgot to add `@Configuration`. Is this example of code working? see here for more ->https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.m3/reference/html/creating-bean-definitions.html

Comment: I am not sure but maybe parent class (WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter ) has `@Configuration`. You are extending it so it may be inherited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are in a such case, take a look at the documentation, here [@Bean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html) documentation you can see that it is not mandatory to use `@Bean` in a `@Configuration` class:

> @Bean methods may also be declared within classes that are not annotated with @Configuration. For example, bean methods may be declared in a @Component class or even in a plain old class.

If you also take a look at `@EnableWebSecurity` [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/EnableWebSecurity.html) you can see that it includes `@Configuration`.

**EDIT**: Hints

For a Spring Boot application, when we use `@EnableWebSecurity` we disable security auto-configuration, so it's preferable to simply doing something like this:

```
@Configuration
// @Order(...)   we can set the order of the filter chain
public class SecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
      // configuration here
}
```

In this case we keep the configuration provided by Spring Boot + our own configurations.

Comment: Thank you akuma8! What is security auto-configuration? I don't understand why it is recommended to use Configuration than EnableWebSecurity in a Spring Boot app.

Comment: @elvis The use of auto-configuration is more a matter of convenience and time saving than a matter of recommendation. About Spring Security, see here for more details: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-security-autoconfiguration